# Can't run "ng add @angular/material" in Ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I'm trying to add Angular Material to my Ionic Angular app. Lots of tutorials online seem to instruct me to run the command:

> ng add @angular/material

I receive this error:

> The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I understand it's an Ionic project and not just a regular Angular project. I just don't understand why others seem to be able to run it fine.

Has anyone experienced this problem before or know a fix? Cheers.

Comment: are you running this in a correct directory ? if your ionic project is setup with Angular it should work

Comment: I’m looking to use angular material’s expansion panel.